# How to use FilterModifier?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent

There is a default customer grid with 1 custom field. By default SQL query for this field contains `LIKE` function. I'd like to replace it with strict `=`.

There is a special method to apply Filter modifier.
`\Magento\Ui\Component\Filters\Type\AbstractFilter::prepare`

But I can not understand how to register my own modifier in magento and use it.

Any examples and explanation are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be used via GET/POST params.
    `$filterModifier = $this->request->getParam(self::FILTER_MODIFIER);`

See `\Magento\Ui\Component\Filters\FilterModifier::applyFilterModifier` to figure out structure of array with modifier params.

#### Example:

Suppose we need to modify Customer Grid filter.

1. Send to controller following param:

`filters_modifier[custom_column][condition_type]=eq`

`&filters_modifier[custom_column][value]=123123`

url example: *example.com/backend/mui/index/render/?namespace=customer_listing&search=&filters[placeholder]=true&paging[pageSize]=20&paging[current]=1&sorting[field]=entity_id&sorting[direction]=asc&isAjax=true&filters_modifier[custom_column][condition_type]=eq&filters_modifier[custom_column][value]=123123*

2. `FilterModifier::applyFilterModifier`  method parses it and add filter to DataProvider.
3. Resulting SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `customer_grid_flat` AS `main_table` WHERE (`custom_column` = '123123')
```